# DatePicker Widget (NOT Dialog) OnDateSet / OnClick event?

Tags: android, dialog, datepicker, widget

How do I know when the date has been changed in a DatePicker widget? OnClick does not fire and there are no other useful events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just saw that it has an `init()` function where you can pass an implementation of `OnDateSetListener`.

Answer (score 0):

`init()` has `OnDateSetListener` but it doesn't work when you click on the text field and change the date using the keyboard.